# Checking if url parameter exists and adding it to registration fields

Tags: javascript, html, url, parameter-passing, textfield

I have a registration flow which is working great, name, dob, email, etc. submit, done.
I also have a function where the user might come from somewhere else that knows there email address and it might be passed in the url. I would like my reg flow to check the url for the parameter and enter the email in the reg form.

So my basic input code looks like this...

```
<input type="email" id="your_email" placeholder="enter e-mail adresse">
```

If I append the url to include &email=123@abc.com, I can successfully pass the email in the url, grab it from the url and enter it into the input box like this...

```
<?php
$email = $_GET['email'];
?>
<input type="email" id="your_email" placeholder="enter e-mail adresse" value="<?php echo $email;?>
```

This is great and works. But, if someone arrives at the page and we haven't passed the email, then the email field is populated with the url token.

I'm wondering if anyone has a good idea to get around this please?
I thought about saying...

the url contains empty parameter 
use the normal code with an empty box

use the new code with prefilled email

...but I'm not sure how to code HTML inside a script.

I found this code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
<body>
    <input id="para1" type="email" value="Check URL" />
</body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#para1").on("click", function () {
            if (window.location.href.indexOf('?book=') > 0) {
                console.log("The URL contains ?book");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</html>
```

...but I would need to change the consol.log section to have the input code.

Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: _"This is great and works"_ - works, but is not _great_, because you just created a XSS vulnerability. _"But, if someone arrives at the page and we haven't passed the email, then the email field is populated with the url token"_ - what token are you talking about? And why would the email field be automatically get filled with it, the code you have shown should do nothing of the sort?

Comment: <?php
$email = $_GET['email'];
?>

Comment: This code gets the email from the url - &email=123@abc.com. I have it at the start of the file, before the HTML.

Comment: <?php echo $email;?> this code inserts the email into the input box.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But it is unclear what happens in the _other_ case you are talking about, when this parameter is _not_ set in the URL. You said if it was _not_ there, then the input field was filled with the "URL token."